# SharePoint central administration first login not accepting credentials

Tags: administration, sharepoint-farm

I have created a SharePoint farm on a VM with Windows 2012 R2. After installation and configuration , during the first login into the central administration page it is asking for my credentials but it is not accepting the credentials even though they are correct. Once I enter the credentials it keeps asking again and again.

Comment: whilst it seems strange to experience this "bug" on a VM, have you tried adding the CA site to the trusted internet zone (or any other zone for which you have enabled the auto-forward credentials feature)? Try this, if it fails, I fear you should try to add a few more details to your question (for example, have you by chance tried to configure the farm to use Kerberos?)

Comment: DisableLoopbackCheck, that is problem

Answer (score 2):

It seems like an issue with loopback check.

Try to make registry changes as below https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepoint_foxhole/2010/06/21/disableloopbackcheck-lets-do-it-the-right-way/

1. Open path `HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa` and Create a dword `DisableLoopbackCheck`. Add a value of 1 to this new entry.
2. Open path `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa` and Create a dword `DisableLoopbackCheck`. Add a value 1 to this entry.

Now restart the VM.

Comment: While this is correct, and if it solves the OP question, great!  But this is not best practice for a secure production farm.  http://www.harbar.net/archive/2009/07/02/disableloopbackcheck-amp-sharepoint-what-every-admin-and-developer-should-know.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable **DisableLoopbackCheck** at the following registry path

> Open registry > navigate to >  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > System > System >
>   Control > Lsa > add new key > Rename key with DisableLoopbackCheck >
>   set to 1

You can check visual steps [here](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/02/26/configure-alternate-access-mapping-in-sharepoint-server-2013/)

Answer (score 0):

I know its far to late and the question was asked like 4 years ago, but the real correct solution is not to disable loopback, as it's pretty much bad practice.

The problem is that the browser can't pass your windows credentials to the central administration site, unless you define it on the machine you're using:

Go to:
**Internet Explorer > Settings > Internet Options > Security**

Now for **Internet, Local intranet** and **Trusted sites**, click on the **"Custom level..."** button and scroll all the way down to **User Authentication > Logon** and change the value to **"Automatic logon with current user name and password"**

This should fix the problem.